# Can MySQL database dumps created with phpMyAdmin be imported on the command line?

Tags: mysql, command-line, import, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL database dump file which I am trying to import on the command line, using:

```
mysql -u my_user_name -p database_name < filename.sql
```

The import fails with this error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 42: Duplicate entry 'comment_publish_action' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I don't understand this error.  Here's the complete text of the dump file (it's short):

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.8
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Mar 18, 2015 at 02:36 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.37-cll
-- PHP Version: 5.4.23

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `database_name`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `aa_actions`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aa_actions` (
  `aid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique actions ID.',
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The object that that action acts on (node, user, comment, system or custom types.)',
  `callback` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The callback function that executes when the action runs.',
  `parameters` longblob NOT NULL COMMENT 'Parameters to be passed to the callback function.',
  `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Label of the action.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores action information.';

--
-- Dumping data for table `aa_actions`
--

INSERT INTO `aa_actions` (`aid`, `type`, `callback`, `parameters`, `label`) VALUES
('comment_publish_action', 'comment', 'comment_publish_action', '', 'Publish comment'),
('comment_save_action', 'comment', 'comment_save_action', '', 'Save comment'),
('comment_unpublish_action', 'comment', 'comment_unpublish_action', '', 'Unpublish comment'),
('node_make_sticky_action', 'node', 'node_make_sticky_action', '', 'Make content sticky'),
('node_make_unsticky_action', 'node', 'node_make_unsticky_action', '', 'Make content unsticky'),
('node_promote_action', 'node', 'node_promote_action', '', 'Promote content to front page'),
('node_publish_action', 'node', 'node_publish_action', '', 'Publish content'),
('node_save_action', 'node', 'node_save_action', '', 'Save content'),
('node_unpromote_action', 'node', 'node_unpromote_action', '', 'Remove content from front page'),
('node_unpublish_action', 'node', 'node_unpublish_action', '', 'Unpublish content'),
('system_block_ip_action', 'user', 'system_block_ip_action', '', 'Ban IP address of current user'),
('user_block_user_action', 'user', 'user_block_user_action', '', 'Block current user');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;t
```

This was generated by going to the Export option, switching to the custom export mode, and selecting just the table aa_actions to export.  Everything else was left on the default settings.

What's going wrong?  How do I get MySQL to accept this file?  I suppose I could install phpMyAdmin on my dev server specifically to import this one file, but what a pain that would be.

Comment: Yes they can, for sure.  Not sure what is going wrong though.

Comment: *"ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 42: Duplicate entry 'comment_publish_action' for key 'PRIMARY'"* Maybe one of the id's being inserted already exists?

Comment: Oh gods, I am such an idiot.  The phpMyAdmin file isn't adding a ``DROP TABLE`` command.  The ``mysqldump`` utility that I usually use does that by default.  The solution is to manually empty the database before doing the import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the man page of mysqldump

```
   ·   --add-drop-table

       Add a DROP TABLE statement before each CREATE TABLE statement.
```

or

```
   ·   --insert-ignore

       Write INSERT IGNORE statements rather than INSERT statements.
```

Its likely your restoring a similar database, so either the data needs to be wiped before restore (first option) or the errors need to be ignored (second option)

WARNING:

The first command Destroys existing data, the second ignore any other errors not caused by duplicate keys.

Without knowing a little more about what it is you want to do, These are 2 "general" solutions

as a note, `--opt` contains option 1 and *should* be enabled by default

Comment: The dump file definitely needs a ``drop table`` or similar in it, but the ``--add-drop-table`` switch is for ``mysqldump``.  The dump file above was generated with phpMyAdmin, which doesn't use mysqldump.  Instead, it turns out you have to check a box labeled "Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT statement" which is not checked by default.